# Reading c++ 2d array in python swig

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy, swig

C++ part
I have a class `a` with a **public** variable 2d int array `b` that I want to print out in python.(The way I want to access it is `a.b`)

I have been able to wrap the most part of the code and I can call most of the functions in class a in python now.

So how can I read b in python? How to read it into an numpy array with numpy.i(I find some solution on how to work with a function not variable)? Is there a way I can read any array in the c++ library? Or I have to deal with each of the variables in the interface file.

for now b is `<Swig Object of type 'int (*)[24]' at 0x02F65158>` when I try to use it in python

ps:
1. If possible I don't want to modify the cpp part.

2. I'm trying to access a variable, not a function.

So don't refer me to links that doesn't really answer my question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question would be easier to answer if you could add a code snippet of your C++ definition (or C if you use int**). When you say "2d int array", do you mean a general int**? Is the array size known in advance?

At any rate, you could probably use [numpy.i](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/swig.interface-file.html) but it depends on the fine details of your array.

See this somewhat related question:
[Swig and multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30259591/swig-and-multidimensional-arrays)

Comment: Yes, it's a general int** and it has 2 possible size. I already know how to make it work with adding code snippet in the c++ definition. But I'm still looking for a way to make it work by only editing the interface file or the python part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll find that passing things back and forth between languages is much easier if you use a one-dimensional array in which you access elements using, e.g. `arr[y*WIDTH+x]`.

Since you are operating in C++ you can even wrap these arrays in classes with nice `operator()(int x, int y)` methods for use on the C++ side.

In fact, this is the internal representation which Numpy uses for arrays: they are all one-dimensional.